# How to guarantee only one construction of an object returned by value?

Tags: c++, raii

I'm trying to implement a class, say `Foo`, which follows RAII, and objects of the class are returned to the client by value, i.e.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
  class Foo {
    public:
      ~Foo() { /* follow raii */ }
    private:
      friend class SomeClass;
      Foo() { /* follow raii */ }
  };

  Foo getFoo() { return Foo(); }
};
```

My immediate question would be is there any way to be sure that only one object of type `Foo` is constructed when calling `SomeClass::getFoo()`?  I would think that most compilers know only one object need be constructed, but I know this is not guaranteed in most cases.  Is there a better approach I can take?

I've tried returning a `boost::shared_ptr<Foo>` and just allocating a `Foo` object when constructing the shared pointer, and this works nicely.  However, it does not seem ideal, as it requires heap allocation and makes for a less-clean interface.

Thanks!

**Clarification**

Visual Studio 2005 compiler so I don't think R-val references and C++11 related features are available.

Comment: You could move the return value and return an rvalue reference, guaranteeing one construction and one move, but I don't see why you would when any sane compiler will do RVO.

Comment: @chris But returning a reference to a temporary object doesn't extend its lifetime. :(

Comment: @sftrabbit, Yes, that too.

Comment: Since you don't state any reason against it, the best approach is probably to give `Foo` a public constructor that puts the object into whatever state `getFoo()` puts it into, and then call that instead of calling `getFoo`. That guarantees only one object constructed. Returning by value relies on an optimization that is implemented by any serious compiler, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've taken the best approach. The copy (or in fact move in C++11) will almost surely be elided by the compiler. In fact, even the copy from the return value to some object in the calling code will probably be elided too. So this will only call a single constructor:

```
Foo foo = sc.getFoo();
```

The rule that allows both of these copies (or moves) to be elided is:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

Comment: What I'm most concerned about is that I have to guarantee that only one object is constructed/destructed from this function call, otherwise the `SomeClass` object state will most likely elicit unexpected behavior.  Is this still acceptable with comment/unit tests, or does this suggest shared_ptr?

Comment: @jwalk Why on earth would copying `Foo` cause unexpected behaviour in `SomeClass`? I'd say you have a problem with your copy constructor if that's the case. A copy constructor should not have any extra side effects.

Comment: Most compilers utilize return-value-optimization (RVO) even in debug builds. There is no guarantee, but you can easily verify by adding some couts in your constructors and assignments.

Comment: @sftrabbit you're right, the constructor and destructor for `Foo` were not symmetric, that was the underlying issue.  Destructor was releasing ownership of an object that constructor was simply assigning.

Comment: @jwalk, if you want "moveable" semantics in VC8 (VS2005), you might look into how `std::auto_ptr` is implemented. It is admittedly a poor man's substitution for move semantics, but it might help you, in this case.  I implemented something similar using those semantics that works on VC9 & g++ 4.1.2 in order to return a read-lock from a caching API (after the cache made sure it was in proper order).

Answer (score 1):

## boost::optional + boost::in_place

If copy constructor is dangerous, it is better to disable it completely.
Though most of compilers would elide copies in your case, some times it is possible to disable copy elision, for instance [-fno-elide-constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) - and if code which "believes" in copy-elision would happen to run on such settings - there may be [fireworks](http://www.detroitmommies.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/fireworks.jpg).

In C++98 you may use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) + [boost::in_place](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/in_place_factories.html) - there is no heap allocation, becuase boost::optional reserves enough place. And it is **guaranteed** that there will be no any copies.

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e68a1c3135d07f9e)

```
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

struct Foo: private noncopyable
{
    explicit Foo(int i)
    {
        cout << "construction i=" << i << endl;
    }
};

void make(optional<Foo> &foo)
{
    foo = in_place(11);
}

int main()
{
    optional<Foo> foo;
    cout << "*" << endl;
    make(foo);
    cout << "!" << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
*
construction i=11
!
```

This code does work on MSVC2005.

---

## Boost.Move

Another option is to use move semantic emulation for C++98 - [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/move.html). Copies are disabled:

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d33f43aefda6e5)

```
#include <boost/move/utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class Movable
{
    BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE(Movable)
    bool own_resource;
public:
    Movable()
        : own_resource(true)
    {}
    ~Movable()
    {
        cout << (own_resource ? "owner" : "empty") << endl;
    }
    Movable(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) x)
        : own_resource(x.own_resource)
    {
        x.own_resource = false;
    }
    Movable& operator=(BOOST_RV_REF(Movable) x)
    {
        own_resource = x.own_resource;
        x.own_resource = false;
        return *this;
    }
};

Movable make()
{
    return Movable();
}

int main()
{
    Movable m = make();
}
```

Output is:

```
empty
empty
owner
```

This code also does work on MSVC2005.

---

## C++11

In C++11 use following approach:

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd1bdb12ec9fd0e8)

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(const Foo &)=delete;
   Foo(Foo &&)=delete;
   Foo &operator=(const Foo&)=delete;
   Foo &operator=(Foo &&)=delete;

   Foo(int){}
};

Foo create()
{
   //return Foo{0}; // ERROR: needs Foo(self &&)
   return {0};
}

int main()
{
   auto &&t=create();
}
```

Foo is created only once, it's copy and move constructor are deleted - it is **guaranteed** that there will be no any copies or moves.

Comment: My copy constructor was dangerous because of bad design, but thanks for the boost references.

Comment: @jwalk, If copy constructor is dangerous - you can disable it. I showed two approaches which do not have any potential copies and both work on VS2005.